# Parallel update of lists in list of lists

Tags: python, list, parallel-processing

I'm trying to speed up some code. My goal is to find a faster/parallel way to update individual lists in a list of lists. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
import numpy as np

indx = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0])
val = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])

list_of_list = _np.empty((4, 0)).tolist()

for i in range(6):
    list_of_list[indx[i]].append(val[i])
```

The `indx` array is unknown, but the upper bound is known, while the structure of `val` is known (so I demoed it as seen above). The solution will be a list that looks like `[[0, 1], [1, 1], [0], [0]]`

Is this the only or fastest way to reach the solution? Or are there better ways to solve this riddle? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Updating lists is so fast that the overhead of adding parallelism will probably make it slower.

Comment: But if you have an enormous number of lists to update, you might get some benefit by using a few threads that each update a subset.

Comment: @python_user By using multiple cores

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much for your swift answer and input - that is reassuring to know. What would be a list size when I would start using multiple threads? Would you have a link with an explanation on how to approach this?

Comment: You'd have to benchmark to be sure, but I think thousands.

Comment: Note that there are [profilers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) that come with your python installation. `cProfile` is actually REALLY easy to get started with and it will help you understand why your code is so slow. Maybe you've used it and are coming at this with that information already, but if you're not, I'd recommend profiling *first* to see what is really slowing down your code. You might find that you don't need parallelization.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, my list will be easily several thousand elements long, probably 300k and above. If no one has a smart suggestion, though, I will try to leave it as is.